# p:messages autoUpdate="true" does not auto update during p:dataTable cell edit event

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, datatable, message

I have two issues with an editable data table with a custom validator that performs business logic validation.

First issue is that when custom validator throws validation exception, those are not shown in p:growl or p:messages. But the field is highlighted red, so I know validation failed as expected. Shouldn't messages automatically show as per autoUpdate="true" attribute?

Second issue is that, let's say an user input an invalid value, so validation fails, and user clicks "Save" button anyway. I was expecting Primefaces to call validation again, and not perform the action. However, the action of the commandButton is called (only the model is not updated with the invalid value provided by the user). I was expecting that Invoke Application phase would not be called without running validation phase again? When I debug my validator is called AFTER the commandButton action is called.

I have a main page that includes another xhtml file (code of a dialog), has a form and a growl.

**main.xhtml**

```
<ui:include src="/pages/dialog.xhtml" />
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>
    ...more code
```

and the dialog where editable data table is displayed
**dialog.xhtml**

```
<p:dialog>
    <h:form id="dialogForm">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" />

        <p:dataTable editable="true" editMode="cell" value"#{myBean.list}"
            var="item">

            <p:columns value="#{myBean.columns}" var="column">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item[column].value}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="{item[column].value}" validator="inputValidator">
                            <pe:keyFilter mask="pnum" />
                        </p:input>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>

        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{myBean.save}"
            update="dialogForm"/>
    </h:form>
<p:/dialog>
```

**validator**

```
@FacesValidator("inputValidator")
public class InputValidator implements Validator{
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
        Object value) throws ValidatorException {

        boolean valid = ...validation code;

        if(!valid){
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Invalid", "Invalid value provided.");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);

            ((UIInput)component).setValid(false);

            throw new ValidatorException(msg);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using primefaces 5.2 and myfaces 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

Never used such validator but I think you should add your message to context.

```
context.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Domen. However I got in the console of my WebServer:  "There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered" and then the message used to generate the Exception. Prime (or myfaces) add those to the context...

Comment: I managed to work-around and force display the message with `<p:ajax update=":dialogForm:msgs" event="cellEdit" />`. However I still have the issue where validation is not performed when user clicks Save button. Seems that combination of custom validator + editable datatable with edit model cell causes the validation to be invoked only during onchange event of the field. 

As part of my problem is not resolved, I believe the question should remain open. Let me know otherwise.

Comment: One last thing, I tried using `args.validationFailed` to prevent user submitting the form thru Save button, but got "args is undefined error". I believe that when using custom validators, args is not set?!

Comment: This answer is wrong. This is only applicable when you're performing validation in a class which is not a real validator.